# MyDocuments/IIsexpress folder got deleted

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I accidentally deleted the "MyDocuments/IISExpress" folder and now my MVC project doesnt load in Visual Studio 2012. Is there any way to recreate that folder? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i got it handled.
Turns out all you have to do is to open cmd.exe and redirect IIS to another folder to force automated creation:

C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress /userhome:C:\MyDocs\IISExpress
where "C:\MyDocs" is the new root location for your Documents folder.